# Robustly estimate statistical model in image

Tags: matlab, math, image-processing, distribution, gaussian

As you known, we have many statistical model to represented intensity image. But each model will satify for specical image. I want to estimate best statistical model for my given image. My idea is that I will build my given image as histogram distribution and then I will construct a statistical model (Ex: gaussian, Rayleigh...). After that, I will choose best model base on min square error compare with histogram distribution. How to do it in matlab. Thank you so much. Or if you have other idea to estimate it, please suggest

Comment: If you have the curve fitting toolbox, it could help you to fit with whatever function(s) you like. Otherwise you'll have to program yourself the whole thing and then your question gets quite complex.

Comment: If you have the partial derivatives of your statistical model respect to each parameter, you can use gradient descent.

Comment: @Wli: Do you know the curve filting toolbox software? I only know one tool that name is Curve Expert tool. But it does not have gaussian mixture model or other model. It only have some basic non-linear function

Comment: I meant the curve fitting toolbox in matlab. You need an additional license for it. Then you need to input manually your equations. the results of fit(...) gives you also a R² and adjusted R², so you don't need to do too much work. http://www.mathworks.fr/fr/help/curvefit/index.html

Comment: Also I would advise you to use cumulative distribution function instead of histograms. Then it is bin-size independent.

Comment: Thank you so much. I done it

Comment: @Wli: I tested it and see that distribution of MRI image is similar Gaussian distribution. Do you know other kind of model that best than gaussian distribution?

Comment: I don't know, I think stackoverflow is not the right place to ask that. You should check the board about statistics. Also I will add an answer to this post so that you can tick it as answered... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said it in the comments, use the curve fitting toolbox offered by Matlab. Half of the work is already done there, you just need to input the right equation in there.
mathworks.fr/fr/help/curvefit/index.html

I strongly suggest you to use cumulative distribution functions instead of histograms. Then you can use the integral of your models.